# Resolve value in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, promise

I have the following code:

```
function doSomething() {
  //xhr here 
  setTimeout(function() {
     var value = 42;
  }, 10);
  return {
    then: function(callback) {
      callback(value);
    }
  };
}

doSomething().then(function(result) {
    log("got a result", result);
});
```

And can't figure out how to access the value. 
I need this to be promise-based solution in order to use in multiple places
[JSFidle link](http://jsfiddle.net/bxysuo9p/)

Update: 
We are not using any libraries in that projects

Comment: Everytime you define a new function, you create a new scope, and variables defined within that scope are not available outside it. The variable is inside the scope of the timeOut

Comment: And just returning a `then` function does not a promise make.

Comment: **Warning** - returning a `then`able that does not conform to the spec is risky and may cause unexpected results. It _might_ work but it's not that simple - consider using a promise library and reading [this excellent blog post](http://modernjavascript.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/promisesa-understanding-by-doing.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just pointing out, that in order to "fix" your issue you need to return the `then` this way:

```
function doSomething() {
  //xhr here 
  return {
    then: function(callback) {
       setTimeout(function() {
          callback(42); // callback from within the async action
       }, 10);
    }
  };
}

doSomething().then(function(result) {
    log("got a result", result);
});
```

Please read TJ's answer and consider using a promise library - also consider reading [this post](http://modernjavascript.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/promisesa-understanding-by-doing.html) that explains how promise resolution looks like.

Namely: Your `then` needs to in turn return a promise when called (rather than just set a timeout) for chaining, and the callback should be assimilated before waiting for it.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of problems there:

1. `value` is local to the function you're passing into `setTimeout`, because that's where you've declared it. You could fix this issue by declaring it in `doSomething` instead.
2. The bigger issue is that what you have there isn't a promise, it's just a function that returns an object when you call it that has a `then` method. Here's the order in which things happen:

   1. You call `doSomething`
   2. It sets a timer to set a value.
   3. It creates an object with a `then` function.
   4. It returns the object.
   5. You call the `then` function immediately.
   6. `then` tries to access `value` (which it can't because of the declaration issue, but would be a problem anyway).
   7. **Some time later**, `value` is set by the callback when the timer fires.

   To be a promise, the `then` function on object you return would have to store a reference to the callback passed into it, and call the callback **later**, when `value` has been set (e.g., the promise has been fulfilled).

Rather than implementing your own promises library, I'd suggest using one of the several that have already been written and debugged.